# How to find out the length and friction costs of my least cost path?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I modeled different possibilities for transmission lines with the GIS tool "Cost Path". Now I would like to find out more information about my results. First of all: Where can I see the length of my least cost path? Second: I generated my input costs raster based on different weights for different land covers. Now I would like to find out how many km my transmission line goes through each land cover type. How can I do that? (In my weighted overlay, I gave every land cover type another weight).

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2

Comment: GIS.SE works best on the premise of one question per question. You seem to have two distinct questions here, so you should probably edit your post to focus on one and ask/research the other separately.

Answer (score 1):

Convert path to polyline and calculate its length or lengths of the segments in its attribute table by right clicking on one of the empty columns (if there is none add one) and then selecting Calculate Geometry option. Friction costs can be extracted to the new table by using Stack Profile.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I can now calculate the length of my polyline. Could you explain a bit more how the stack profile works and if I then can see for how many kilometers the line goes through different land covers.

Comment: Stack Profile will create a table and optionally a graph that will show how cost changes along path. You can read about in at the following link: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q9000000mm000000